# Optimizing for data that does not fit in memory

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, aggregate

We have a database that contains around 235 GB of data (calculcated using `pg_total_relation_size` for each table) on a server with around 77GB of memory. The server is used for nothing else (aside from SSH, backup and similar administrative stuff). We are running **postgres 9.2**.

I extracted one table of 13GB and tested it on a seperate server with 4GB of memory to benchmark some queries, indexes, etc. outside of our production environment. I had some questions for this which can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468982/avoiding-external-disk-sort-for-aggregate-query.

On the seperate server, the queries use index-only scans and run relatively fast (compared to pre-index creation with sequence scans). The same queries against the same table on the production machine does a sequence scan almost no matter what settings I set up (short of setting `seq_page_cost` lower than `random_page_cost`, which is a Bad Idea(tm).)

Our workload is to extract analytical data - we have around 10 columns that are raw numbers that we do a lot of `SUM()` aggregate queries on, usually grouped by an item ID. The data is updated constantly, mostly with `UPDATE` queries to existing rows to update per-day data is it comes in during the day (so a row for a specific day may be updated ~20 times in one day). The 13GB table is for one of our biggest customers and have around 6 million rows.

The customized settings from the production config looks like this:

```
shared_buffers = 20000MB
effective_cache_size = 56000MB
work_mem = 512MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2048MB
checkpoint_segments = 64
temp_buffers = 16MB
max_stack_depth = 4MB

wal_level = archive
archive_mode = on
archive_timeout = 6h
checkpoint_timeout = 1h
wal_writer_delay = 100
wal_keep_segments = 32
```

I am looking for some insights for how to create indexes (and alter queries), as obviously in the larger setup the query planner acts differently based on the amount of data.

- Is it better with small indexes that only cover the small parts of the query to help with lookups or full covering indexes (for index-only scans)?
- Does the above setup match my server specifications and workload?
- Any good tips to speed up aggregate queries (mainly `SUM`) for all rows and grouped by item ID (I am aware we may need to look into column-store databases)?

Also, does any of the above stand out as being "wrong" or should I modify it? We are running it off locally attached disks, but backup is being sent off to NFS disks (SAN).

Answer (score 2):

it is important to know, which queries you are running.
otherwise it is close to impossible to give you any real advise.

however, there are two things you should know:

- UPDATE benefits nicely from a thing called FILLFACTOR. it can speed up things a lot.
- the order of columns does have an impact on the size of the table (http://www.cybertec.at/shrinking-the-storage-footprint-of-data/). it can change things quite nicely

but as i said: i got to see your queries to really help.

Comment: Does fillfactor matter for INTEGER / BIGINT columns? We have 1-2 text columns that may get re-filled (where it would matter), but otherwise it seems that it would always take up the same space (I assume it reserves enough bytes for a complete 32/64-bit integer).

Comment: in general the rule is: keep identical data types next to each other. for integer it is fine but as is said: same types -> close together.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is updated constantly, you will have a hard time getting the benefits from index-only scans.  They are mostly effective on read-only or read-mostly data.

If that is the case, adding columns to the index will likely be counterproductive.  If any of the constant stream of updates were into previously-unindexed columns, those could have benefited from HOT updates, but now they can't.